# Manage sync calls in async method .net 4.5

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

I have a question regarding sync call inside an async method.

I have 5 I/O calls in one async method. 3 of them have async api that I can use but 2 of them are sync (request for web service without async api). My question is what is the best practice for this situation?

1. I can wrap the sync calls in `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` and take thread from the pool but in the video you mentioned that it's could actually can hurt the concurrency.
2. I can leave the sync calls as they are but the TAP recommends that the synchronous work done by a TAP method should be the minimum amount possible and avoid sync long-running operation inside the async method.

I'm little bit confused what the correct way to go here.

Comment: Put all those I/O to 1 only async method and that's it.

Comment: “in the video you mentioned” What video are you talking about? Who is this “you”?

Comment: this is the link for the video
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET

Comment: What kind of application is this? Windows cliente? ASP.NET? Windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize StartNew with a custom SynchonizationContext, or you can set the Task as LongRunning. LongRunning tasks use they own thread. It will hurt someway the performance (more threads running on the system overall), but will not have impact on other things running on ThreadPool.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoThingy(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
```

You can see here about TaskSchedulers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx .

Comment: but if its hurt the preferment little bit it still the best way to go
and leave the calls as sync its even worth no?

Comment: That will depend, there is no problem in stalling the ThreadPool for some seconds if your server don't need such high throughput, just leave it that way. The ThreadPoll will fire more Threads to keep up. I would do some tests before, you can use the Visual Studio Concurrency Viewer, it's a good tool for those optimizations.